# Passing in rails routes to AJAX url value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I have an app where a user has a portfolio that has many positions and each position has many movements. So the url for an associated movement index page for a particular position looks like: portfolio_position_movements. I have an index page with and the controller action looks like

```
def index
  @movements = @position.movements.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @movements}
  end
end
```

My ajax call in my movements.js file is this:

```
var loadData = function(){
            $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              url: ?,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){
                drawBarPlot(data);
              },
              failure: function(result){
                error();
              }
            });
          };
```

How can I pass in a dynamic route path so this will work with the movement index on any position object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use erb tags in js files, for me i did it as the following:

```
#edit.js.erb

$modal = $('.modal'),
$modalBody = $('.modal .modal-body'),
$modalHeading = $('.modal .modal-heading');
$modalHeading.html("Edit <%= @student.full_name.titleize %>'s information");
$modalBody.html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'edit_student') %>");
$modal.modal();
```

Note: the file extension is `.js.erb` so rails can process it. I was calling a modal form and the edit method in students_controller.rb was:

```
 def edit
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # edit.html.erb
      format.js # edit.js.erb
      format.json { render json: @student }
    end
  end
```

Edit:

You can embed the JS code inside html.erb and use rails routes like:

```
<script>
var loadData = function(){
            $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              url: <%= my_ajax_path %>,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){
                drawBarPlot(data);
              },
              failure: function(result){
                error();
              }
            });
          };
</script>
```

What is my_ajax_path?

Is a rails route defined in `routes.rb` for example i need a list of all available sections that students can apply to using ajax so i did the following:

1- defined a method in students_controllers.rb like this one:

```
  def available_sections
    batch_id =  (params[:batch_id].nil? || params[:batch_id].empty?) ? 0 : params[:batch_id].to_i

    if batch_id == 0
      @sections = [].insert(0, "Select Section")
    else
      batch = Batch.find(params[:batch_id])
      # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
      @sections = batch.sections.map{|a| [a.section_name, a.id]}
    end
  end
```

2- added a route to it in `routes.rb`

```
resources :students do
  collection do
    get :available_sections
    post :create_multiple
  end
end
```

3- Inside new.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.student_section_id').hide();
    $('#student_batch').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/students/available_sections",
            data: {
                batch_id : $('#student_batch').val()
            },
            dataType: "script",
            success: function () {
                if (+$('#student_batch').val() > 0)
                {
                    $('.student_section_id').fadeIn();
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.student_section_id').fadeOut();
                }
            } 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Forget about that messy code :D as it was my first steps but you get the point, and for this line `url: "/students/available_sections"` it should be using rails routes you can get it by calling `rails routes` from the command line to get a list of all your application routes

Comment: I have a movements.js file. How can I get the value in that file? Or do you just place script tags in the html file?

Comment: Where do you define my_ajax_path?

Comment: my_ajax_path is a route which should be defined in `routes.rb`